# Building JavaScript objects representing a tree

Tags: javascript

```
function createObjects(element, depth){
    element.label = element.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    element.url = element.getElementsByTagName("url")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    element.depth = depth;
    if(treeWidths[depth] == undefined){
            treeWidths[depth] = 1;
    } else {
            treeWidths[depth]++;
    }

    element.children = new Array();
    allNodes.push(element);

    var children = element.getElementsByTagName("children")[0].childNodes;
    for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
            if(children[i].nodeType != 3 && children[i].tagName == "node"){
                    element.children.push(createObjects(children[i], depth+1));
            }
    }

    element.expanded = false;
    element.visible = false;
    element.moved = false;
    element.x = 0;
    element.y = 0;

    if (getNodeWidth() < element.label.length * 10)
            element.width = element.label.length * 10;
    else
            element.width = getNodeWidth();
    element.height = getNodeHeight();
    return element; }
```

Having problems with Firefox, it says that 'element.children.push' is not a function but works (only) in Google Chrome...

Any clue?

Comment: What's going on with those "getElementsByTagName()" calls, where the tag names are "url" and "children"?  What sort of content is that?  What is "element"?

Comment: @Pointy: the tag names are from an XML file which is phrased (with JS), here ( http://www.4shared.com/file/5kD6WzWr/Tree.html ) are the zipped files

Comment: OK so what does "element" refer to?  If it's an HTML DOM node, then the reason Firefox complains because it's not letting you set the "children" attribute in the first place; that's a built-in read-only attribute of all HTML element nodes.

Comment: @Pointy: Any cross-browser solution here?

Comment: Well it's hard to say because it's unclear what you're doing. Your question title is about "JavaScript objects", but it looks like you're actually trying to build the DOM. If that's what you want to do, then you have to use the DOM APIs as @citizen conn described in that answer.

Comment: @Pointy: live demo here: http://open-cs.net/tree/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.children = new Array();
```

I wouldn't add an array as a property of an element. If you want to add children to an element, this is not the right way. Also if you want to just use an array to manage data, this is not the right way either.

If you want to add child elements use:

```
element.appendChild(createObjects(children[i], depth + 1));
```